# Custom SOAP 1.1 header and mustUnderstand attribute

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xsd, axis

My WebService (compilant with SOAP 1.1 specification) uses its own type of header *MyHeader* defined within the xsd as follows:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyHeader">
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="MyElement1" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
       <xs:element name="MyElement2" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Unfortunately SAOP message generated "by AXIS 1.4 framework" has *MyHeader* element containing *mustUnderstand="0"* attribute:

```
<ns:MyHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns="http://....">
   <ns:MyElement1>XXX</ns:MyElement1>
   <ns:MyElement2>YYY</ns:MyElement2>
</ns:MyHeader>
```

According to specification SOAP *mustUnderstand* can be added to each header. However, it seems to me that the so-defined elements *MyHeader* can not contain this attribute, because the resulting XML is incompatible with the XML specification - it does not valide against XML rules of *cvc-complex-type*.

Is it allowed to add *mustUnderstand* attribute to this header instance?
Does AXIS framework 1.4 works properly?

Answer (score 0):

To keep a long story short, please search for "removing mustUnderstand attribute from headers" and that should get you the solution; by default, this header shouldn't be added; if you have a need to actually use it, then I would modify your schema for the header part to include these SOAP attributes; if you want to see an example, please take a look at [WS-I Claim schema](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/ConformanceClaims-1.0-2004-11-15.html) (remove use="prohibited").

Comment: I know that here are techniques for removing this attribute on producer and consumer sides. But important question is: putting mustUnderstand is allowed and conforms to specification SOAP/XML? Can this attribute added even xsd contains use="prohibited"?

Comment: @Max, it shouldn't; yes, mustUnderstand is allowed for literal (as opposed to encoded); the best practice in this space is to make sure that your header types extend from an "attributed" base type that allows for anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContent="lax".

Comment: @Petru Is there a conventional example of such a type to extend from?  I have tried adding an anyAttribute with namespace="##other" and processContent="lax" to my own header type directly, but this hasn't solved the problem for me.